# Magento: stuck on billing information

Tags: magento, checkout

hi i got stuck on billing information, am unable to proceed to the order review step from shipping method.please anyone let me know what i should do to resolve this.

i have changed the following code in 
magento\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\onepage\payment.phtml

```
<form action="" id="co-payment-form">
   <fieldset>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

to the bellow code

```
<form action="" id="co-payment-form">
   <fieldset id="checkout-payment-method-load">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

But still am unable to resolve the issue

my site is on live in this 
url http://avsoftwares.com/demo/magento

Admin panel : http://avsoftwares.com/demo/magento/admin

username: demo
password: demo123

please please help me with this.. thank you.

Comment: hello,try to disable your theme and check it.

Comment: i done the same and it worked for the default theme. now in my theme files where and to which file i should make changes to make it work.

Comment: hello, try to rename of checkout.xml from your theme and check it

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be a prototype error. http://avsoftwares.com/demo/magento/js/prototype/prototype.js line 612 - lastPrice is not defined.
It's encoutering this error and failing. 
You could look here to begin with. (firebug will tell you more)

You could also try with the default theme and if it works you know it's an error in your theme files (provided you haven't edited the core...). Go to System->Config->Design and set the package to default and leave all other fields empty. This will tell magento to use the base default template files and not yours.

Comment: Hi sulman thanks for the reply i changed the design to default and it worked nicely.and as u said may be the problem in my theme files, but now the question is in which file i need to make changes to make it work. please do reply me please...

Comment: The Protoype error may be a red herring. It looks like there is custom JavaScript running. If you are familiar with grep I would grep you theme files like so grep -r -H "if (!lastPrice)" * This will list all occurences of this code. And it is here where there is a problem. You could also look in "checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml" as the custom JS might be in there.